# How to customize the input type range with our costum css styles

Tags: css, input, range, styles, input-type-range

I have tried a lot of variants of custom `input[type="range"]` styles.
I have tried the most relevant answer, but it's not worked.

Can anyone help me? I have the worst designer I have ever met, so I need to make this anyway.

Without change:

[image]

In the middle:

[image]

On finish:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried already.

Comment: While you can style the thumb slider and also color the progress bar you might have difficulty getting a gradient 'tail' as it appears we can't attach a pseudo element to the thumb. You may need some Javascript, is this acceptable?